# Where do I find the mail/message icons?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

Where can I find the official mail/message icons shown below?

[image]

So I can add them to a button. They are not under any of the button Types on the story board Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following application allows you to obtain `UIBezierPath`s for your own drawings.

http://www.paintcodeapp.com

A more elegant solution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can find icons on "http://www.flaticon.com/".

You can get any icon from this site easily with different formats of icons any size u want with any color

Comment: thanks - but it appears you have to pay for them or credit the author. neither option i really want to do.

Comment: No, I use it already and its totally free. You can get free. Click on download free then the dialogue box open to download. It seems that they want to pay for that but its for premium users but when u get icons for free why want to pay for it

Comment: For the free download you *must credit author*. also i was wondering why there are no official ones released by apple?